# jpa's changes are not reflected at H2 database

Tags: java, database, jpa, intellij-idea, h2

I'm writing the code which is related with one-to-many one way mapping.

In that process, i face a problem.

I changed the intellij codes, but h2 database's tables don't change.

The image below is the result(h2 database table).
[image]

and these are the four java class files.

```
`package hellojpa;

import org.example.Main;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.List;

`your text`
`public class JpaMain {

    private static Team team;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello");

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        try{

            Member member = new Member();
            member.setUsername("member1");
            em.persist(member);

            Team team = new Team();
            team.setName("teamA");
            team.getMembers().add(member);
            em.persist(team);

            tx.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            tx.rollback();
        } finally{
            em.close();
        }
        emf.close();
    }
}`
`
```

```
package hellojpa;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
        public class Member {
        @Id @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "MEMBER_ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "USERNAME")
        private String username;

        public Long getId() {return id;}

        public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

        public String getUsername() {return username;}

        public void setUsername(String username) {this.username = username;}


}
```

```
package hellojpa;

public enum RoleType {
    GUEST, USER, ADMIN
}
```

```
package hellojpa;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Team extends Member {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<Member> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
}
```

and this is the result running the codes.

```
C:\jdk1.8\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=57451:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\jdk1.8\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\이소정\IdeaProjects\untitled\target\classes;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.3.10.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.3.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.10.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.2-GA\javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.5\byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\이소정\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\2.1.214\h2-2.1.214.jar hellojpa.JpaMain
11월 08, 2022 11:52:05 오후 org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: hello
    ...]
11월 08, 2022 11:52:05 오후 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
11월 08, 2022 11:52:05 오후 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
11월 08, 2022 11:52:06 오후 org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
11월 08, 2022 11:52:07 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
11월 08, 2022 11:52:07 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test]
11월 08, 2022 11:52:07 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa}
11월 08, 2022 11:52:07 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
11월 08, 2022 11:52:07 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
11월 08, 2022 11:52:07 오후 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table Member if exists
Hibernate: 
    
    drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
11월 08, 2022 11:52:09 오후 org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@503d56b5] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
11월 08, 2022 11:52:09 오후 org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    drop table Member if exists" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    drop table Member if exists" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at hellojpa.JpaMain.main(JpaMain.java:16)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot drop "MEMBER" because "FKE8UEUS37RRMKA8U5STQRU9V0A, FK15N138CXCXM0P0V68XQU8H76F" depends on it; SQL statement:

    drop table Member if  [90107-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.DropTable.prepareDrop(DropTable.java:97)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.DropTable.update(DropTable.java:121)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:408)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.readException(SessionRemote.java:637)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:606)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:227)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:252)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 15 more

11월 08, 2022 11:52:09 오후 org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@30c0ccff] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: 
    
    create table Member (
       DTYPE varchar(31) not null,
        MEMBER_ID bigint not null,
        USERNAME varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        TEAM_ID bigint,
        primary key (MEMBER_ID)
    )
11월 08, 2022 11:52:09 오후 org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    create table Member (
       DTYPE varchar(31) not null,
        MEMBER_ID bigint not null,
        USERNAME varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        TEAM_ID bigint,
        primary key (MEMBER_ID)
    )" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table Member (
       DTYPE varchar(31) not null,
        MEMBER_ID bigint not null,
        USERNAME varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        TEAM_ID bigint,
        primary key (MEMBER_ID)
    )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at hellojpa.JpaMain.main(JpaMain.java:16)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MEMBER" already exists; SQL statement:

    create table Member (
       DTYPE varchar(31) not null,
        MEMBER_ID bigint not null,
        USERNAME varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        TEAM_ID bigint,
 [42101-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:91)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:408)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.readException(SessionRemote.java:637)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:606)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:227)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:252)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 15 more

11월 08, 2022 11:52:09 오후 org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table Member 
       add constraint FKo2n5sg34stgq6nnp4q98eyorw 
       foreign key (TEAM_ID) 
       references Member" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table Member 
       add constraint FKo2n5sg34stgq6nnp4q98eyorw 
       foreign key (TEAM_ID) 
       references Member" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at hellojpa.JpaMain.main(JpaMain.java:16)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "TEAM_ID" not found; SQL statement:

    alter table Member 
       add constraint FKo2n5sg34stgq6nnp4q98eyorw 
       foreign key (TEAM_ID) 
       references  [42122-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:749)
    at org.h2.table.IndexColumn.mapColumns(IndexColumn.java:184)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:214)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:72)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTable.update(AlterTable.java:46)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:408)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.readException(SessionRemote.java:637)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:606)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:227)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:252)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 15 more

11월 08, 2022 11:52:09 오후 org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@5851bd4f'
Hibernate: 
    
    alter table Member 
       add constraint FKo2n5sg34stgq6nnp4q98eyorw 
       foreign key (TEAM_ID) 
       references Member
Hibernate: 
    call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: 
    call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Member
        (USERNAME, DTYPE, MEMBER_ID) 
    values
        (?, 'Member', ?)
11월 08, 2022 11:52:10 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
11월 08, 2022 11:52:10 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.MEMBER(MEMBER_ID) ( /* key:1 */ 'Member', CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'member1', NULL)"; SQL statement:
insert into Member (USERNAME, DTYPE, MEMBER_ID) values (?, 'Member', ?) [23505-214]
11월 08, 2022 11:52:10 오후 org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
11월 08, 2022 11:52:10 오후 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: First question: why do you expect it to have changed at all? You have to configure JPA DDL generation  and it really only offers two options; create it or drop and create it (se https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema ). The error you are getting shows it certainly is trying to issue some DROP DDL statements to clean up your database. In this case, it cannot because the drop script it has and is using is wrong for the state of the database. You will need to see if you have a script from before your latest changes you can run, or manually drop the schema yourself.

Comment: answer for question : the table should be changed cuz i change the codes..! the table is not the result that i intended. the problem that i face is ; "i change the code but the table is not changed"

Comment: You haven't shown what configuration you are using, and no tool in existence can read your mind. It needs configuration to tell it what to do and how to handle the various use cases and edge cases that crop up. In this case, I would guess (since not details are given) that you are using drop and create options. Since your model has drastically changed since the DB was generated last, the drop script is wildly different from what would be needed. It is a situation that needs manual intervention, hence the warnings! I've told you what to do so you'll need to reframe your question

Answer (score 0):

If This is usually configured in your persistence xml:

For an example see the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property here:
https://gist.github.com/jorgevs/218483e7ba854e8e6e23be18182b0381

Comment: so do you mean i should copy persistence xml code in the link and paste?